# Why my google search macro is returning error 424 - Object required?

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have this simple macro that opens up IE and type a word in search box. It was working before, but now is returning

> Error 424 - Object required.

Any ideas on what is happening? Is there any lib reference that I'm missing?

```
Sub AcessaPaginaDados()
    Dim xobj As HTMLDivElement
    Dim ie As Object

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate ("https://www.google.com/")

    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set xobj = ie.document.getElementById("lst-ib")
    Call xobj.setAttribute("value", "teste")        
End Sub
```

Comment: What line errors?  Is it copied code missing the HTML references used for `xobj` do you have a new version of web browser?   Has something changed in the environment since?

Comment: On which line is error?

Comment: you need to remove the parenthesis here `ie.Navigate ("https://www.google.com/")`

Comment: Actually this is part of a big search and fill vba and I find this piece with error. The error line is the Set xobj = ie.document.getElementById("lst-ib")

Comment: Removed the parenthesis and used the `[title=Pesquisar]` solution and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That id doesn't appear against the input box when I open google. You can use an attribute = value selector to target the `title` attribute of the search box. Right-click inspect the search box and see what your local language attribute value is for title=. In U.K. the value is `Search`. Use whatever your local value is.

**Element html:**

[image]

**Other:**

Also, `.navigate2` is the preferred method.

If the page is slow loading you may need a loop until element present.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AcessaPaginaDados()
    Dim xobj As HTMLDivElement

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.google.com/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set xobj = .document.querySelector("[title=Search]")
        xobj.Value = "teste"

        Stop
        .Quit
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Tried your code and got the same error on Set xobj = .document.querySelector("[title=Search]")

Comment: Did you check what your html gives as the title attribute value? If it doesn't say _Search_ and says something like _Buscar_  then you need to change to  [title=Buscar]

Comment: If the page is slow loading you may need a loop until element present. If you can confirm what the title value is for the attribute and that it still doesn't work I will add loop code in above.

Comment: Thank you everyone! @QHarr I updated the code with your solution and it worked like a charm. My local value was `[title=Pesquisar]`